# I can' t run docker in macOS

Tags: docker, macos

I have a new mac mini m2 and can't get docker to run hello-world.

I have installed docker using brew install --cask docker.

I installed docker desktop and it shows the docker engine is running. I get this from terminal output:

```
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/markhorrocks/.colima/default/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % docker --version
Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/markhorrocks/.colima/default/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

None of the fixes I have found on SO work for me.

```
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % ls .colima
_templates  _wrapper    default     docker.sock ssh_config
```

in .zshrc

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$HOME/.colima/docker.sock"
```

also

```
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % colima delete
are you sure you want to delete colima and all settings? [y/N] y
INFO[0006] deleting colima                              
INFO[0006] done                                         
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % colima start
INFO[0000] starting colima                              
INFO[0000] runtime: docker                              
INFO[0000] preparing network ...                         context=vm
INFO[0000] creating and starting ...                     context=vm
INFO[0021] provisioning ...                              context=docker
INFO[0021] starting ...                                  context=docker
INFO[0027] done                                         
markhorrocks@Marks-Mac-mini ~ % docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix://Users/markhorrocks/.colima/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: I don't bother with `homebrew` for `docker`, or `colima` whatever that is. I just go to https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/ and install it and it all works superbly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the Docker Desktop Application in order for the daemon to start. If I type `docker ps` in my terminal I get the same error as you do, if I don't run the App first. The little whale symbol will appear on the top bar of your Mac when it starts running.

Comment: I finally installed colima using the ddev instructions which worked.

Comment: Did you manage to use docker without Colima on macos?